# I’m looking for a entry level road bike under $500

Tags: road-bike

I’m a 15 year old who’s looking to move from mountain bikes to road bikes, can you give me some suggestions on what to look for in a entry level bike.

Comment: http://www.bikesdirect.com is probably the best site in the internet for seeing what kinds of bikes are available, and getting good US pricing for different levels of bicycles.  Note that if you buy from them, they ship you a partially-assembled bike that often needs a bit of work before it can be ridden, so don't buy from them if you don't know how to put a bike together (or don't know someone who does...)

Comment: Thx for the recommendation  :)

Comment: You're 15?  Then don't waste money on a new bike.  You're still growing so sizing becomes a problem.  Buy a **used** road bike that fits you, and learn what you do/don't like.  And by about 18 you will have stopped physically growing longer, so then is a good time to buy a full-sized bike.